# how to generate test report in selenium 2 java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

i am using eclipse for coding selenium 2 tests and it takes values from the excel row wise and col wise.Now in excel sheet i wanted to add a new col saying "RESULT" .now how can i write the test result (pass / fail ) against this col for each row while test ng runs

Answer (score 0):

```
if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
{
   writeToExcel();
}
```

You didn't put Excel as a tag so I assume you know how to write the values there, but don't know how to tell if the test passed. I believe the above will do it, but I don't have Selenium installed on this machine so you might just want to give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

testNG provides methods to add listeners which will tell you whether a test passed or failed. You can override the `onTestFailure, onTestSuccess` methods and define methods to write the value to the excel sheet. You can see details on listeners [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am using Apache POI to read and write data to Excel.
To check if the test case is passed or failed, you can use *try - catch* around assertion.
If any of the assertion fails, it means your test case has failed and then you can mark that test case as FAIL in Excel inside the catch block.

Make sure to use below command at the end of catch block

```
Assert.fail(e)  // where e is the exception captured
```

This will make TestNG report this execution as FAIL. If this is not used then TestNG will report this execution as PASS.

Below is the function I have used to write my results to Excel:

### Variable details

```
FilePath = excel file path
_Sheet = Worksheet name
result = Pass / Fail string that you want to print in excel
static int _TC01_ROWCOUNTER = 1; // Defines the row number of first data element in test data excel sheet.
    static int _TC01_COLUMNCOUNTER = 3; // Defines the Column position in which Result needs to be printed in test data excel sheet.
```

### Function details

```
private void writeToExcel(String FilePath, String _Sheet, String result) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            _testdatastream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);  

            try
            {
                wb = new HSSFWorkbook(_testdatastream);  
                ws = wb.getSheet(_Sheet);

                try
                {
                    HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(_TC01_ROWCOUNTER);
                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(_TC01_COLUMNCOUNTER);
                    cell.setCellValue(result);
                    _testdatastream.close();

                    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FilePath);  
                    wb.write(fileOut);  
                    fileOut.close();

                    _TC01_ROWCOUNTER++;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.logger("Could not write result to test data file because of following reason"+"\n"+e,"ERR:");
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Logger.logger("Mentioned worksheet"+_Sheet+" not found in test data file"+"\n"+e,"ERR:");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.logger("Test Data file not found at location:"+FilePath+"\n"+e,"ERR:");
        }
    }
```